# Rounded corners in IE7 and IE8

Tags: html, javascript, internet-explorer

Now every major browser supports `border-radius`, I was wondering what the best way to get rounded corners in IE7 and IE8 is until IE9+ becomes most dominant version of IE.

I've seen several javascript based solutions, but I was wondering if anyone could recommend one they've used themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This web page explains how to do it.](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers)

Comment: Nice little hack, thanks. I went with CurvyCorners.js because it doesn't require me to change any of my HTML or CSS.